# getJSON: why does the 1 example work, but the other not?

Tags: jquery, json

I have 2 examples of a function that retrieves json-data and gives an alert.

In this example, everything goes fine: http://jsbin.com/uwupa3/edit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var timeService = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?";

  $.getJSON(timeService, function(data) {
    alert(data);
  });
});
```

But in the second example, there is no alert displayed.
Why? The only difference is the service where the json is retrieved. The json-object looks perfectly valid to me: http://jsbin.com/uwupa3/2/edit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var timeService = "http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=Europe/Brussels";

  $.getJSON(timeService, function(data) {
    alert(data);
  });
});
```

I get no JS-errors. I also tried this local (so not on JSbin but with a htm-file on my pc) and this doesn't work either.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using an URL that's outside your domain, which means `$.getJSON` will not use an XmlHttpRequest, but some JSONP -- see the [documentation of `$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) :

> If the specified URL is on a remote
>   server, the request is treated as
>   JSONP instead. See the discussion of
>   the jsonp data type in `$.ajax()` for
>   more details.

And if you take a look on the documentation of the `jsonp` option for [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you'll see :

> Override the callback function name in
>   a jsonp request. This value will be
>   used instead of 'callback' in the
>   'callback=?' part of the query string
>   in the url for a GET or the data for a
>   POST. So {jsonp:'onJsonPLoad'} would
>   result in 'onJsonPLoad=?' passed to
>   the server.

And for the `jsonpCallback` option :

> Specify the callback function name for
>   a jsonp request. This value will be
>   used instead of the random name
>   automatically generated by jQuery.

For your first request, there is a `jsoncallback` parameter in the URL ; for your second request, there is no such parameter :

- First URL : `http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?`
- Second URL : `http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=Europe/Brussels`

I suppose this has something to do with the fact the second request doesn't do what you want ?

Comment: I added `&callback=?` to the second url, and now it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation :-)   *(I didn't try ; glad to know it works ! )*

Answer (score 1):

You are using an URL that's outside your domain, which means `$.getJSON` will not use an `XmlHttpRequest`, but some `JSONP` -- see the documentation of $.getJSON :

> If the specified URL is on a remote server, the request is treated as
>   JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax()
>   for more details.

And if you take a look on the documentation of the jsonp option for $.ajax, you'll see :

> Override the callback function name in a jsonp request. This value
>   will be used instead of 'callback' in the 'callback=?' part of the
>   query string in the url for a GET or the data for a POST. So
>   {jsonp:'onJsonPLoad'} would result in 'onJsonPLoad=?' passed to the
>   server.

And for the jsonpCallback option :